# if you define a variable inside a loop, is it still defined after the loop is closed?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

if we define the value of `a = something` inside a for loop.
When the loop finishes, will `a = something` continue to be true or will it be reset after the loop is finished?

Comment: it still be true, you need to reset it manually

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It will continue to be defined until it is assigned a new value or a destructor is applied to it (e.g. when exiting the sub when **a** has been declared within the sub).

Additionally, something like a [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) can have the value of the increment evaluated after the loop has been exited.

```
dim i as long, lr as long
lr = 500

for i = 1 to lr
    if i > 99 then exit for
next i

if i <= lr then
    debug.print "did not finish loop"
else
    debug.print "finished loop"
end if
```